# Can a player with 0 life use Soul Conduit to make their opponent lose instead?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you get a player down to 0 life can he still use [Soul Conduit](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20Conduit)'s ability and swap life totals with another player killing that player instead?

Answer (score 9):

No, unless the player has a "Cannot lose" effect in play, like [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel).

When a player goes to 0 life, before priority is regained (and the player able to activate Soul Conduit), state-based actions are checked and the player loses the game.

Even if the ability were on the stack, it doesn't resolve before state-based actions, again. (e.g. 1 life, activate Conduit, use [Underworld Connections](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Underworld%20Connections))

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that.

When you go down to zero life, you lose the game immediately, before you have a chance to do anything.

The exception is if you have a card that prevents you from losing the game for having 0 or less life, such as [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel) or [Phyrexian Unlife](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phyrexian%20Unlife). If you have one of those, then you will be able to act while you have 0 life, and you will have the opportunity to set another player's life total to 0.